# C# Winform - Detecting whether two events were fired by one user action

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling

I have a Winform's combobox, and of course I need to know when the user chooses an option. The problem is that each event type has its disadvantage:

textChanged doesn't fired when the choosing happens with closed drop down list (but by focusing the combobox and moving up and down with keyboard arrows).

SelectionChangeCommittedHandler isn't fired when the drop down list is open, the user goes up and down by keyboard arrows and then click by the mouse either on the combobox title or outside.

SlectedIndexChangedHandler is fired too much times so it will slow the program in cases of weak web connection.

So I thought to do that solution:

Register to both SelectionChangeCommittedHandler and textChanged events and in cases that both are fired, ignore one of them. The problem is that I don't know how to detect that situation (= two events from one user action).

I'd be glad to know how to detect that, or, if there, to hear about better solution.

Comment: "SlectedIndexChangedHandler is fired too much times so it will slow the program in cases of weak web connection." - If Network I/O blocks your UI, then you are "doing it wrong" anyway ... What are you actually trying to achieve? What is your goal?

Comment: @Fildor On selecting value in one combobox, I fill the next combobox with data that I get ad hoc by calling to web service with the selected value as parameter. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Depends on some points: 1. How many items does the combo contain? 2. Is it fast enough to only fetch after the selection has been committed? 3. How many Items can there be in the dependent Combo? ... What I am aiming for is: Would it make sense, to for example "pre-fetch" all possible Item-Lists of the second Combobox? And do you really need to fetch the items on every change? ( = Do you need to *see* the items change in 2. combo when scrolling through 1. combo ?)

Comment: Also: Would it make sense to keep once fetched ItemLists remotely in a local cache? (Thus minimizing Network traffic)

Comment: @Fildor Actually I do what you are suggesting, but only partially (on rest of comboboxes), because pre-fetch of all options is too much data and hence will slow the load process.

Answer (score 1):

A bit dirty, but I'm trying to give you a solution: listen for both events and mark a timestamp each time one of them fires. Once the event fires, check current time vs last operation time and, given a tolerance you'll decide, continue with your program logic only if a certain amount of time is elapsed since the last operation.

I imagine something around 100 milliseconds would suffice but try it yourself.